# UIScrollView targetContentOffset not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I understand that there are other questions out there but those now are outdated and not updated for iOS 7. The issue that I am having is that setting the target content offset isn't working only on a specific `if` condition. The scroll view doesn't scroll to the targetContentOffset I have set, it just scrolls and decelerates normally. I'm basically trying to recreate the paging feature using custom width pages. This scroll view is added to a UITableViewCell and is Auto Layout is disabled.

Here is how I set up my scroll view:

```
UIScrollView *myScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
myScrollView.frame =  CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 85);;
myScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(776, 85);
myScrollView.pagingEnabled = NO;
myScrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
myScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
myScrollView.delegate = self;
myScrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(228, 0);
myScrollView.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast;
```

These are my delegate methods:

```
-(void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    lastCellOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.x;
    //Sets the offset the scrollview is scrolling from
}

-(void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset {
    if (scrollView != self.tableView) {

        if (velocity.x > 0.0 || velocity.x == 0.0) { //If scrolling or dragging left i.e. going to the right

            if (lastCellOffset == 0.0) {         //If dragged from first page
                *targetContentOffset = CGPointMake(228.0, 0); //Set content offset to second page

                lastCellOffset = 228.0;           //Not completely necessary I think

                NSLog(@"Left - to page 1"); 

            } else if (lastCellOffset == 228.0) { //If dragged from second page

                *targetContentOffset = CGPointMake(548.0, 0); //Scroll to second page NOT WORKING IF X > 228.0
                lastCellOffset = 548.0;

                NSLog(@"Left - to page 2");       //Called!
            }
        }

        if (velocity.x < 0.0 || velocity.x == 0.0) {
            if (lastCellOffset == 228.0) {
                *targetContentOffset = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0);
                lastCellOffset = 0.0;
                NSLog(@"Top1");
            } else if (lastCellOffset == 548.0) {
                *targetContentOffset = CGPointMake(228.0, 0.0);
                lastCellOffset = 228.0;
                NSLog(@"Bottom1");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am only getting one `NSLog` per drag so I know its not cancelling itself out somehow or resetting to a different position and only the conditional I want called is called.

Edit: if I set the `content offset.x` to anything less than `228.0`, it works?

Comment: What isn't working? What is happening instead? What is the "special condition" you are referring to?

Comment: Also note that if `velocity.x == 0.0` then both conditionals will get entered. I doubt you intended this.

Comment: See my second point (about both methods getting called). Also, have you verified your scroll view's `contentSize.width` is large enough for a `targetContentOffset` of `548`?

Comment: @AaronBrager Yes the `contentSize` is `{778.0, 0.0}` and I know both conditionals are called if `velocity.x == 0.0` but it's `>0` when I'm testing it and the `targetContentOffset` is `548.0`.

Comment: @Milo One side note this condition `velocity.x < 0.0 || velocity.x == 0.0` can be simplified to `velocity.x <= 0.0`. And same for other too.

Comment: @AaronBrager Edit: if I set the `content offset.x` to anything less than `228.0`, it works?